# confusion about differential eq question

Tags: python

i was using sympy to solve Differential eqs  this was the code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDZHX.png)

what does that C mean in the output and also is the answer right?Im new to solving D.E and im actually clueless where to start with

Comment: The answer is right. If you are not familiar with the differential equations you cannot understand why an arbitrary constant C appears in the solution. Don't use a tool whitout knowing the intended use of the tool.

Comment: you are right actually the teacher taught us about it but I quite actually didn"t get it so I was trying  this way If i can get my head going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C1 is an arbitrary constant. It appears during the integration. Let's try to solve the equation. ($f(x) = y$ for simplicity)

$-5y+y'=2$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=2+5y$

$\frac{1}{2+5y}dy=dx$

Then we integrate both sides. Notice that an arbitrary constant will appear since the integration is not definite.

$\frac{1}{5}ln(5y+2)=x+C$

$5y+2=e^{5x+C}=e^{5x}e^C$

Since $e^C$ is a constant, we can substitute it with an arbitrary constant which is $C1$. You can try to solve for $y$ and you will get the result.

Comment: thanks a lot really appreciate the help